# Compare Images From Pylon GigE Camera Video Feed using absdiff

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to grab two pictures from an basler GigE camera video feed with pylon and opencv. The two pictures are converted to grayscale and compared using absdiff. The pixels that have changed should be the object i'm looking for.

Here is the while-loop of the code.

```
while(camera.IsGrabbing()) {

            camera.RetrieveResult(5000,ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);      

            if(ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()){
                formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
                openCVImage1 = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *) pylonImage.GetBuffer()); 
            }
            else{
                cout<<"ERROR OpenCVImage1:" <<ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode()<<ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription()<< endl;
            }

            camera.RetrieveResult(5000,ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
            if(ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()){
                formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
                openCVImage2 = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *) pylonImage.GetBuffer());
            }
            else{
                cout<<"ERROR OpenCVImage2:" <<ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode()<<ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription()<< endl;
            }


            cvtColor(openCVImage1,grayImage1,CV_BGR2GRAY);

            cvtColor(openCVImage2,grayImage2,CV_BGR2GRAY);

            absdiff(grayImage1,grayImage2,differenceImage);
            imshow("DiffImage", differenceImage);
            threshold(differenceImage,thresholdImage,sensitivity, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

            switch(waitKey(10)){
                    case 27: //ESC
                        return 0;
                    case 116:    //t
                          trackingEnabled = !trackingEnabled;
                            if(trackingEnabled=false) cout<<"tracking disabled"<<endl;
                         else cout<<"tracking enabled"<<endl;
                          break;
                    case 112:       //d 
                         debugMode=!debugMode;
                     if(debugMode==false){cout<<"Code paused, press 'p' again to resume"<<endl;
                         while (pause==true) {
                             switch(waitKey(0)){
                                    case 112:   //p
                                      pause = false;
                                      cout<<"Code Resumed"<<endl;
                                      break;
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
        //do stuff 
        }
```

I have three problems doing that.

First: `The differenceImage is always black`. Altough I'm moving in fornt of the camera. Probably I'm not grabbing the pictures correctly. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Already tried to add a waitKey(10) before the second RetrieveResult.

Second:  `The switch(waitKey(10)) is not working`. No Matter what i press on the keyboard, there is no output on the screen. Already tried it using if and else if, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Third: `If i stop debugging and start debugging again, i get an exception caught by my catch block`. Probably this is because the camera didn't stop Grabbing after i stopped debugging. If i plug the camera out and back in the script runs. I tried using stopGrabbing() and close() but it didn't work.

I'm using windows 7 with visual studio 2010!! 
Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: have you tried showing/saving the image before absdiff?have you checked what waitKey gives you? it is recommended to use it with & 255 to remove extra bits that some systems introduce to it (alt, shift, ctrl, numslock etc can be in the first bits of the return value)

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes it is possible to both show and save the gray images. i solved the waitKey problem. i was trying to type into the console. but i have to type in the opencvwindow. Do you have a solution for the third problem maybe?

Comment: if camera is class member you can try putting in the destroyer the close part... however, not all crashes or ways of terminating the program pass through here and do it elegantly... but that would be my best guess/suggestion